# Browser and Webserver api authentication tokens

Tags: authentication, model-view-controller, oauth, owin

I am currently working on a solution that includes a multi tenant webApi which will be accessed by multiple clients, some of which i will be creating, some of which others will be creating. 
Access to the api will be available via an ApiKey & Secret (enough for some resources) as well as username & password (for owner resources).

At the moment, the clients i have created (.Net MVC Web apps) have their own membership systems so what happens is the user of the client logs into the client system and the client system passes the login information to the Api to retrieve an authentication token.

The client membership system is really an unneeded abstraction. What i really want to do is have the user log directly into the api and the api pass back an authentication token that can be used from the browser as well as the .Net MVC client app.

My question is, what it the best way to achieve this. In my mind i seem to be struggling with 2 solutions.

1) Have a browser based login (ajax/AngularJS for instance) solution that calls the api to retrieve a token which then passes that token onto the MVC client where it will be stored (session variable maybe). Any future calls to the api that come from the .Net MVC client can pass the token on. This seems wrong to me though. I'm not even sure this is possible.

2) Utilise one of the OAuth flows so that the browser based login can call the API and retrieve a token, and the OAuth flow redirects to the MVC client which then stores the token for that user (again, in a session variable).

The Api was generated using the VS2013 WebApi template using Owin local accounts and is generating tokens via the ValidateClientCredentials and ValidateResourceOwnerCredentials flows, but i think i need to use one of the other OAuth flows for this scenario.

I understand that another solution would be to bypass the .Net MVC client code and create a completely browser based solution using knockout or AngluarJS but it's quite a complex system and i don't really have time to do this at the moment so i'm looking for a solution that would allow me to retrieve a token from the api that can be used from my .Net MVC client and ajax calls from the browser.

Any ideas, advice would be much appreciated.

thanks in advance. Justin

Answer (score 0):

If you'd rely on Azure AD as your credentials store and authentication system, you'd be able to leverage a ready to use JS library that handles authentication, AJAX calls and session management concerns automatically: see http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/10/28/adal-javascript-and-angularjs-deep-dive/.
If you can't rely on Azure AD, the code of the library and samples mentioned above can still have value as a reference to build your own system - provided that the authenticaiton system you decide to use offers similar capabilities.
HTH
V.